# Where to subscribe/unsubscribe to UIKeyboardWill(Show|Hide)Notification?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, notifications

Let's say I've got a handful of view controllers, each of which has some textviews/textfields/webviews. There's one main view controller (MainViewController), and the rest are displayed using `presentModalViewController:animated:`.

**EDIT**: I want to clarify that I'm not using UINavigationController — the main view controller is just a normal UIViewController, and others are displayed as modal view controllers from time to time.

I wonder how I should implement the keyboard notification subscription so that the subviews within the top most view controller can be resized correctly. I've tried 2 approaches:

1/ Subscribe to UIKeyboardWill(Show|Hide)Notification in `viewDidLoad`, and unsubscribe in `dealloc`.

Problem: Multiple view controllers get notified at the same time, resulting in weird layout resizing.

2/ Subscribe in `viewWillAppear`, subscribe in `viewDidDisappear`

Problem: Sometimes `viewWillAppear` isn't triggered, so I got to manually resubscribe to keyboard notifications.

Any advices are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I think , **Subscribe in viewWillAppear and Unsubscribe in viewDidDisappear**   is more preferable then **Subscribe to UIKeyboardWill(Show|Hide)Notification in viewDidLoad, and unsubscribe in dealloc.**

As you mentioned there is only one issue with approach 2.

**Problem: Sometimes viewWillAppear isn't triggered, so I got to manually resubscribe to keyboard notifications.**

Here is the code to make sure your `viewWillAppear` **trigger** always.

http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UINavigationController/viewWillAppear.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a thought, use visibleViewController property of UINavigationController class.

Implement the Notification in the rootViewControllers viewDidLoad method, 
and call a method like updateVisibleViewController where you access your most visible view controller with a call to [visibleViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
-(void)updateVisibleViewController{
   [[rootNavigationController visibleViewController] "trigger your method here"];
}
```

Comment: I don't use UINavigationController, so this is of no use. That said, I've never heard of `visibleViewController` before. Thanks!